# PIL Image Open is not able to open some files in a zip folder

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, zip

I have about 300000 image files in a zip folder. Some of those files have path starting with '__'. PIL function Image.Open() is not able to open these files. Please suggest a way to open them. My code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from PIL import UnidentifiedImageError

problem_files = []
file_paths = []
img_list = []
img_size = (128,128)
with ZipFile('/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/AI_ML/Project2/words.zip') as myzip:
  contents = myzip.namelist()
  for i in range(0,len(contents)-1):
    text = str(contents[i])
    if '.png' in text:
      file_paths.append(contents[i])
  for path in file_paths:

    img = myzip.read(path)

    try:
      img_data = Image.open(BytesIO(img))
    except UnidentifiedImageError:
      problem_files.append(path)

    img_data = img_data.convert('L')              
    img_data = img_data.resize(img_size)
    image_as_array = np.array(img_data, np.uint8)
    image_as_array = np.reshape(image_as_array,(1,-1))
    img_list.append(image_as_array)
```

This puts all the files with path starting with '__' into problem_files list

```
problem_files[-10:]

['__MACOSX/words/j04/j04-070/._j04-070-08-07.png',
 '__MACOSX/words/j04/j04-070/._j04-070-04-07.png',
 '__MACOSX/words/j04/j04-070/._j04-070-04-06.png',
 '__MACOSX/words/j04/j04-070/._j04-070-08-06.png',
 '__MACOSX/words/j04/j04-070/._j04-070-06-03.png',
 '__MACOSX/words/j04/j04-070/._j04-070-06-01.png',
 '__MACOSX/words/j04/j04-070/._j04-070-08-04.png',
 '__MACOSX/words/j04/j04-070/._j04-070-04-04.png',
 '__MACOSX/words/j04/j04-070/._j04-070-04-05.png',
 '__MACOSX/words/j04/j04-070/._j04-070-08-05.png']
```

There are about 100000 images in problem_files list

Comment: You need to provide more information. For example, can some files that start with `__` be loaded? Are the file that cannot be load while in the zip file be loaded if they are manually extracted first?

Comment: Please just share a ZIP file with a single problematic image in it and the code that tries to load it... use Dropbox or Google Drive or similar if StackOverflow can't host the file. Thank you.

Comment: I found out that these images are for users working on MAC and so not applicable to me(working on windows).